# Data conversion error when using CAST in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting the error 'Error converting data type nvarchar to float' when running the following

```
     declare 
     @completeCommand       nvarchar (max) = 'x'
    ,@paramVal              nvarchar (100)
    ,@paramName             nvarchar (100)
    ,@paramType             nvarchar (100)
    ,@tempParam             sql_variant

  declare @parameterList table (
      RowID           int identity (1,1)
     ,ParameterValue  nvarchar (100)
     ,ParameterName   nvarchar (100)
     ,ParameterType   nvarchar (100)
  )

  insert into @parameterList
  values
     ('10', 'Param1', 'int')
    ,('test', 'Param2', 'nvarchar')

  -- Process each parameter one at a time
  declare ParameterCursor cursor fast_forward for
    select ParameterValue, ParameterName, ParameterType
    from @parameterList
    order by RowID

  open ParameterCursor

  fetch next from ParameterCursor into @paramVal, @paramName, @paramType

  if @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    set @completeCommand = @completeCommand + ' '

  while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin

    print @completeCommand

    -- verify the datatype is correct
    set @tempParam = case @paramType
          when 'int' then CAST (@paramVal as int)
          when 'float' then CAST (@paramVal as float)
          when 'nvarchar' then CAST (@paramVal as nvarchar)
          else 'NULL'
        end 

    set @completeCommand = @completeCommand + @paramName + ' = ' + @paramVal + ','

    fetch next from ParameterCursor into @paramVal, @paramName, @paramType
  end

  close ParameterCurosr
  deallocate ParameterCursor
```

What I am trying to do is verify that user entered data matches the expected data type before the data is added to a command string.  Any feedback on why the above code fails would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: Fundamental flaw -- You're relying on user input for data type.  Just because I tag data as "NVARCHAR", doesn't mean it is.  You should consider using ISNUMERIC to confirm before casting to a numeric data type.

Comment: That may be true.  But that doesn't explain why the case statement does not chose the correct WHEN clause.

Comment: Be careful, ISNUMERIC is not an "IsAllDigits" function. Have a look at this article (free registration to site required): http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/IsNumeric/71512/

Comment: @OMG Ponies, ISNUMERIC() is a start, but is if it is your only line of defense between user input and a conversion to a float, you will still have errors.  ISNUMERIC() will not catch many basic problems, try `SELECT ISNUMERIC('$1'),ISNUMERIC('1,234.0'),ISNUMERIC('12e4')` all are reported as being "numeric" but will fail when you cast them to float/numeric/etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that CASE will return the data type with the highest precidence, of which is float for this statement. see [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

To get this `CASE` to work add a bogus `WHEN 'xzy' then CAST (@paramVal as sql_variant)` which will cause `CASE` to use sql_variant as the return data type.

OR remove the `CASE` and use `IF-ELSE`, like:

```
IF @paramType='int'
    set @tempParam = CAST (@paramVal as int)
ELSE IF @paramType='float'
    set @tempParam = CAST (@paramVal as float)
ELSE IF @paramType='nvarchar'
    set @tempParam = CAST (@paramVal as nvarchar)
ELSE 
    set @tempParam = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

What you used was Simple Case function. Searched Case function should work (see below).
I've just tried it in a very simple query:

```
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @value SQL_VARIANT

SET @type = 'varchar'
SET @input = 'test'

SET @value = CASE 
   WHEN @type = 'varchar' THEN @input
   WHEN @type = 'int' THEN CAST(@input AS VARCHAR)
END
```

On SQL Server 2005 I am getting the same error, but the following is from SQL Server 2008 doc:

Simple CASE function:

- Evaluates input_expression, and then in the order specified, evaluates input_expression = when_expression for each WHEN clause.
- Returns the result_expression of the first input_expression = when_expression that evaluates to TRUE.
- If no input_expression = when_expression evaluates to TRUE, the SQL Server 2005 Database Engine returns the else_result_expression if an ELSE clause is specified, or a NULL value if no ELSE clause is specified.

Searched CASE function:

- Evaluates, in the order specified, Boolean_expression for each WHEN clause.
- Returns result_expression of the first Boolean_expression that evaluates to TRUE.
- If no Boolean_expression evaluates to TRUE, the Database Engine returns the else_result_expression if an ELSE clause is specified, or a NULL value if no ELSE clause is specified.

If this is true, then Simple Case will do all the CASTS and then decide qhich one to use, while Searched Case will evaluate the boolean expression and then decide which CAST to execute. This should be the solution.

Otherwise, you can probably use IF ... THEN ... ELSE, as proposed in another answer.

Comment: you quote the same docs that I do, except you quote how the case determines which `WHEN` to use and not what data type is returned.  in the doc, go just before the "Simple CASE function" title and see `Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.` this is the key: `the data type that is returned`, if the case determines to return a float (as it is here) if you try to return a string, you get the convert error.

Comment: continued... As my answer says, modify the CASE so sql_variant is the type returned (it has a higher precedence than float) or just use an IF-ELSE

Comment: I see ... now. I guess I'm WAY to tired to hang around here, answering questions without understanding what I read. You'd better follow KM's advice. @KM: Thanks for pointing this out and not slapping me in the face as I probably deserve tonight...