# Conversion failure converting int to date within an SQL INSERT CASE query

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, azure-sql-database, sqlclient

I have read a number of articles on here (e.g. [Data conversion error when using CAST in a CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892050/data-conversion-error-when-using-cast-in-a-case-statement)) which discuss data type precedence as being the cause of issues like the one I have been struggling with today, but I think mine is different. One my development computer I am running SQL server and have created a database running compatibility level 110.  I have created a table:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SyncDataRecords](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SyncDataID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FldVar] [sql_variant] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SyncRecords_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have another table which lists the fields involved in my application:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SyncDataFields](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SyncDataID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FldName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [FldBaseType] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [PK] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SyncDataFields] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Against this database I can successfully execute the following query from within my application via an SqlClient.SqlCommand parameterised command:-

```
DECLARE @FldTyp NVARCHAR(16);

SELECT @FldTyp = UPPER(FldBaseType)
FROM   SyncDataFields
WHERE  SyncDataID = @SyncDataID
       AND PK = 1;

INSERT INTO SyncDataRecords
            (SyncDataID,
             FldVar)
VALUES      (@SyncDataID,
             CASE
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'SQL_VARIANT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS SQL_VARIANT)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'NVARCHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS NVARCHAR(4000))
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'BIGINT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS BIGINT)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'BIT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS BIT)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'DECIMAL' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS DECIMAL)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'INT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS INT)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'MONEY' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS MONEY)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'NUMERIC' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS NUMERIC)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'SMALLINT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS SMALLINT)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'SMALLMONEY' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS SMALLMONEY)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'TINYINT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS TINYINT)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'FLOAT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS FLOAT)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'REAL' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS REAL)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'DATE' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS DATE)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'DATETIME' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS DATETIME)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'SMALLDATETIME' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS SMALLDATETIME)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'TIME' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS TIME)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'CHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS CHAR)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'VARCHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS VARCHAR(4000))
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'NCHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS NCHAR)
               WHEN @FldTyp = 'VARBINARY' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS VARBINARY)
               ELSE CAST(@FldVar AS SQL_VARIANT)
             END);

SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

As a test I am setting @SyncDataID to 1 (Integer) and @FldVar to 1234 (Integer), which results in @FldTyp being 'INT'. I then created a duplicate database and table hosted with Azure, which defaulted to compatibility level 150.  I can successfully execute this same query via SSMS, declaring the additional variables as necessary.  However if I connect my application to the Azure hosted SQL database it throws an error

> Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed

The only way that I could get my application to succeed was to reduce the compatibility level of the Azure SQL database down to 110 to match my development one.  Even changing CASE to IF ELSE IF didn't help, I still got exactly the same error.

The code I am using which triggers the error is this:

```
objInsPKCommand.CommandText = "DECLARE @FldTyp nvarchar(16);SELECT @FldTyp=UPPER(FldBaseType) FROM SyncDataFields WHERE SyncDataID=@SyncDataID AND PK=1;INSERT INTO SyncDataRecords (SyncDataID, FldVar) VALUES (@SyncDataID, CASE WHEN @FldTyp='SQL_VARIANT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS sql_variant) WHEN @FldTyp='NVARCHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS NVARCHAR(4000)) WHEN @FldTyp='BIGINT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS BigInt) WHEN @FldTyp='BIT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS Bit) WHEN @FldTyp='DECIMAL' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS decimal) WHEN @FldTyp='INT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS Int) WHEN @FldTyp='MONEY' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS Money) WHEN @FldTyp='NUMERIC' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS Numeric) WHEN @FldTyp='SMALLINT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS SmallInt) WHEN @FldTyp='SMALLMONEY' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS SMALLMONEY) WHEN @FldTyp='TINYINT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS tinyint) WHEN @FldTyp='FLOAT' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS float) WHEN @FldTyp='REAL' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS Real) WHEN @FldTyp='DATE' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS Date) WHEN @FldTyp='DATETIME' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS DateTime) WHEN @FldTyp='SMALLDATETIME' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS SmallDateTime) WHEN @FldTyp='TIME' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS Time) WHEN @FldTyp='CHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS char) WHEN @FldTyp='VARCHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS VarChar(4000)) WHEN @FldTyp='NCHAR' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS NChar) WHEN @FldTyp='VARBINARY' THEN CAST(@FldVar AS varbinary) ELSE CAST(@FldVar AS sql_variant) END);SELECT @@IDENTITY;"
objInsPKCommand.Parameters.Add("SyncDataID", SqlDbType.Int)
objInsPKCommand.Parameters.Add("FldVar", SqlDbType.Variant)
objInsPKCommand.Parameters.Item("SyncDataID").Value = 1
objInsPKCommand.Parameters.Item("FldVar").Value = 1234
intPKID = objInsPKCommand.ExecuteScalar
```

Might someone please be able point me in the direction of an explanation as to when something changed, and how I might need to alter my query command so that it will continue to work at compatibility level 150.  Many thanks in advance.

An example of the SyncDataFields table for the records in question :-

| ID | SyncDataID | FldName | FldBaseType | PK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 19 | id | Int | 1 |
| 71 | 19 | name | NVarChar | 0 |
| 72 | 19 | styleCode | NVarChar | 0 |
| 73 | 19 | wholesaleGBP | Decimal | 0 |
| 101 | 19 | brand | NVarChar | 0 |

Comment: What is the exact error message text? Also if you can't repro this in SSMS and only your application code gets it what does that look like? Also side note but things like `CAST(@FldVar AS NCHAR)` without length are very dubious. Also what is the datatype of `@FldVar` parameter?

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)+

Comment: I've not worked with `SQL_VARIANT` much but following your edit... Given that the parameter is of type `SqlDbType.Variant` and the column is of type  `SQL_VARIANT` why do you need this `CASE` at all? Can't you just insert the parameter into the column?

Comment: What data is actually in the table `SyncDataFields`? I agree it seems you don't really need the whole `CASE` at all, except perhaps for the string types.

Comment: I included the CASE statement because I began having issues where the value of @FldVar, which is being populated from a JSON response, was mistaking text which looked like numbers for number (or the other way around, it was a while ago now!).  But from what you are saying, as long as I am careful with the strings I shouldn't need to bother  CASTing the other data types?  I am still interested to know though why my existing command runs against a version 110 database but not 150.

Comment: Interesting. The db-fiddle sql 2022 has no problems with this query either, but it only goes to 140. I'm guessing it's a bug

Comment: although, this combo does crash it: select 'date' as fldbasetype
 , 5 as someValue; so perhaps there's something in the data after all?

Comment: I think you may have narrowed down your problem too much. This conversion issue usually happens due to data type precedence, but if you have a `ELSE CAST(... AS sql_variant)` then `sql_variant` will always have the highest precedence. How about you show us what your *actual* code looks like?

Comment: @Charlieface - I have already included my actual code, just substituting fixed example values instead of the code iterating over my data.  And as I said it works on a 110 databases, in fact I have this working on multiple production systems with on-premise SQL.  It isn't even that my code works for some supplied data types but not other. For now I have gone with the suggestion of removing the CASE statements for everything except the string types.  This allows my code to work for the data I am currently processing (which doesn't yet include tables where a date is the primary key). Thanks.

Comment: OK could you show the data in the `SyncDataFields` table, so we can reproduce the problem fully?